# Android Application is not submitting details to an external database

Tags: java, php, android

I am having an issue with submitting data to a database from within my android application, I have referenced a .php file on the website which we are going to use:

```
public static final String SERVER_ADDRESS = "http://app.basicshosting.co.uk/";
```

and then I am binding the variables that I get from the other Activity to variables which get sent via POST:

```
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<>();
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", user.name));
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user.username));
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", user.password));
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("age", user.age + ""));
```

and finally I am sending the variables to the .php script which I wrote:

```
 HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADDRESS
                    + "Register.php");

 try {
                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
                client.execute(post);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

The PHP source code is located at: http://pastebin.com/JRCCk20X

Thanks

Comment: Please elaborate what is the issue you are getting? If you can put any error log? Or describe that error is at front-end or back-end?

Comment: HTTP Post should use with thread or asynctask. I think it was your problem.

Comment: Hello @LeonarAung thank you for your response, how would I go about implementing this into my application? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try with thread or AsyncTask. Example -

```
 public void updatedatabasethread(){
 new Thread(){

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        yourmethod();
     }

}.start();
```

}

create your httppost under a method() and call that method() with this thread.

Call Thread instead of direct using method.